# UITableViewCell setEditing truncates label

Tags: ios, uitableview, uianimation

I'm trying to animate the content of a custom UITableViewCell by moving a label to the right to create space for the red delete icon. The movement works fine but the whole text gets truncated, which it isn't supposed to, there is no reason to me why it does that because there is enough space. This is what it looks like in the edit state

[image]

This is my code

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {
        self.image.alpha = 0.0;
        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, 0, 30, 44);
    } else {
        self.image.alpha = 1.0;
        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 30, 44);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you very much!

Comment: try increasing the width of the label... CGRectMake(15, 0, 50, 44);

Comment: When I use CGRectMake(15, 0, 50, 44);, only one more letter is visible. When I use the second hint, the label in the cell with the "delete icon" doesn't get truncated, but all the other labels in the other cells still do.

Comment: Do you do it for all the labels or only label in cell with delete icon?

Comment: The code above lives inside the custom cell. In the tableView I only allow content (cells) created by the user to be edited. This is why only the first cell in the picture has a "delete icon". Only these labels should be moved as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    CGRect frame = CGRectZero;

    if (editing) {
        self.image.alpha = 0.0;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(15, 0);

    } else {
        self.image.alpha = 1.0;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(10, 0);
    }

    frame.size = [self.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.textLabel.font];
    self.textLabel.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this was it, the labels don't get truncated. Thanks a lot! With the code above, the label with the delete icon moves a bit up. I changed the following to fix it: frame.origin = CGPointMake(15, 10);

Answer (score 2):

Try using this :

```
self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[self.textLabel sizeToFit];
```

Or you can try this :

```
self.textLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.textLabel.center.x + 5, self.textLabel.center.y);
```

Or you can try this :

```
self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.textLabel.origin.x + 5, self.textLabel.origin.y, self.textLabel.bounds.size.width, self.textLabel.bounds.size.height);
```

Or you can try this :

```
CGSize textSize = [self.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.textLabel.font constrainedToSize:self.textLabel.bounds.size lineBreakMode:self.textLabel.lineBreakMode];
self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.textLabel.origin.x + 5, self.textLabel.origin.y, self.textLabel.bounds.size.width, textSize.height);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, when I use this code the label in the first cell is displayed in 2 (short) lines and the other labels still are truncated.